# How to send sms in windows phone7 in cordova

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova

I am using  window.location.href = 'tel:' + contactno;  and it is working fine. But for sms when i am using  window.location.href = "sms:"+contactno+"?body="+messagetext; it is not working for windows phone7, can anyone help me please  i have tried a lot..

Answer (score 0):

Markup:

```
<pre>
    <div>
        <input type="tel" id="phoneNumbers" />
        <input type="text" id="message" />
    <div>
</pre>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    var message = $('#message').val();
    $.each($('#phoneNumbers').val().split(/[ ,]+/)), function (phoneNumber) {
        SmsPlugin.prototype.send(phoneNumber, message, '');
    });
});
```

The `phoneNumbers` field supports separating phone numbers by commas, whitespace, and comma + whitespace. For example this should work:

```
111111111, 222222222,333333333 444444444, 55555555
```